# How to force Gstreamer playbin use the jpegparse plugin?

Tags: gstreamer

On linux platform, I developed a hardware based Jpeg decode plugin named xxxhwjpegdec to replace jpegdec (software based decode),and I adjust xxxhwjpegdec rank to the highest 257. The xxxhwjpegdec pulgin need jpegparse to parse the jpeg header.
When i use:

```
"gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location="/tmp/MJPEG.AVI" ! avidemux name=t t.video_0 ! jpegparse ! xxxhwjpegdec ! waylandsink"
```

it can play the /tmp/MJPEG.AVI smoothly.
My target is using `"gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///tmp/MJPEG.AVI"` to play the file smoothly by my hardware decode.

But i use `"gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///tmp/MJPEG.AVI"` it use jpegdec plugin, which based software to decode, so it cause  the /tmp/MJPEG.AVI be played not smoothly. I checked the playbin pipeline "jpegparse" is not used.
If i delete the jpegdec plugin,

then use `"gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///tmp/MJPEG.AVI"` , it can't paly the 
/tmp/MJPEG.AVI. I checked the key pipeline is `"filesink--avidemux--xxxhwjpegdec--waylandsink"`, no jpegparse inserted.

I judge the playbin Form two different pipeline by above info,
one is 
**"filesink--avidemux--xxxhwjpegdec--waylandsink(can't play)"** , 
another is 
**"filesink--avidemux-jpegdec--waylandsink(can play)"**. 
Because my xxxhwjpegdec need jpegparse plugin to support it. There is no jpegparse inserted by playbin, *So the playbin can't select the first higher priority hardware pipeline to play, it have to select the second lower priority software pipeline to play it instead.*
So I think the root cause is the jpegparse plugin can not be select by the playbin automaticly.

So, anyone know how to force Gstreamer playbin use the  jpegparse plugin?
Or other solution is welcome! 
Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `playbin` builds the pipeline automatically and currently there is no way to override its choices. You will have to stick to building your own pipeline until that changes

Comment: That's strange. If the rank of your hw decoder is more than jpegdec, then it should pick your decoder.  May be, something wrong with your hw decoder caps  ?

Comment: @ soupybionics
yes, I judge the playbin Form two different  pipeline by above info,one is "filesink--avidemux--xxxhwjpegdec--waylandsink(can't play)" , another is ""filesink--avidemux-jpegdec--waylandsink(can play)".  Because my xxxhwjpegdec need jpegparse plugin to support it. There is no jpegparse inserted by playbin, So the playbin can't select the first higher priority hardware pipeline to play, it select the second lower priority software pipeline to play it.

Comment: If I use "gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location="/tmp/MJPEG.AVI" ! avidemux name=t t.video_0 ! jpegparse ! xxxhwjpegdec ! waylandsink" , it can play smoothly. So the root cause is the jpegparse plugin can not be select by the playbin automaticly.

Comment: @ Rolf of Saxony ,thank you still for your information. Is it possible to modify the playbin code to support this requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

jpegparse outputs:

```
Pad Templates:
  SRC template: 'src'
    Availability: Always
    Capabilities:
      image/jpeg
                 format: { I420, Y41B, UYVY, YV12 }
                  width: [ 0, 2147483647 ]
                 height: [ 0, 2147483647 ]
              framerate: [ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ]
                 parsed: true
```

maybe you can change the sink-caps of your jpegdecoder to inlcude `parsed: true` to indicate that you need parsed jpeg buffers.